# Unassigned local variable when passing integer from database to another form in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to pass an integer into another form in C#. After checking the user's login credentials, I want to get is ID and then pass it into another form. However, I get an error saying that the value I'm trying to pass is an unassigned local variable. Here's my code:

**FORM 1**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (u.Text == "" || p.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter username and password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    else
    {
        try 
        {
            // Query for registration
            string view = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE username = '" + u.Text + "' AND password = '" + p.Text + "';";

            // Start SQL connection
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(view, myConn);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            myConn.Open();
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (myReader.HasRows)
            {
                int id;
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    id = myReader.GetInt32("person_id");
                    //person_id = myReader.GetInt("person_id");
                    MessageBox.Show(id.ToString());

                }
                myConn.Close();

                // Create instance of the form
                Form3 dash = new Form3(id); //unassigned local variable id
                dash.Show(); // Show the form
                this.Hide(); // Hide this current form
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

**FORM 3**

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    int final_id;
    public Form3(int id)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        assignGlobal(id);
    }


    public void assignGlobal(int b)
    {
        final_id = b;
        MessageBox.Show(final_id.ToString());
    }

}
```

I have already imported using `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.` I really cannot figure out why it shows that error. Can someone please tell me where I went wrong? What should I change? Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You while loop might not execute if the reader is empty. So you need to explicitly assign a default value for the `id`:

```
int id = 0;
```

Or you need to handle that case using an `if else` statement.

Also if you expect **one value only**, i suggest that you use `ExecuteScalar` instead of a `ExecuteReader` .

You need to ask yourself a question here : *What should my program do if the reader doesn't return any value ?*

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It worked now. I will try ExecuteScalar. Seriously thank you so much for helping me!!!

Comment: @WandaMaximoff by the way, `myReader.HasRows` always returns false in your case.

Comment: can you explain why?